# Ionic Cordova plugin error: package com.smartadserver.android.library does not exist

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a problem for several days. I hope that you can help me.

I use for a projet the plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-smart-adserver

The build for iOS work fine, but on Android I have this errors:

```
    :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projets/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:12: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library does not exist

import com.smartadserver.android.library.SASBannerView;
                                        ^
/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projets/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:13: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library does not exist
import com.smartadserver.android.library.SASInterstitialView;
                                        ^
/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projets/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:14: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library.model does not exist
import com.smartadserver.android.library.model.SASAdElement;
                                              ^

/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projets/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:15: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library.ui does not exist
import com.smartadserver.android.library.ui.SASAdView;

                                           ^
/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projets/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:16: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library.ui.SASAdView does not exist
import com.smartadserver.android.library.ui.SASAdView.StateChangeEvent;
                                                     ^

/Users/matthieu/Documents/Projet`enter code here`s/MOG002_RadioLac/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/rjfun/cordova/smartadserver/SmartAdServerPlugin.java:17: error: package com.smartadserver.android.library.util does not exist
import com.smartadserver.android.library.util.SASUtil;
```

Have you an idea?

Comment: From the ["Issues" section](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-smart-adserver/issues/5) it looks that the problem has been reported in 2016 and was never adressed. The plugin is old btw (2015)

Comment: I unfortunately saw the message. I hope to find a solution here to solve the problem. To my knowledge there are no other extensions for Smart Ad Server:-(